# Is there any equivalent to iOS of these Cocoa Security Classes?

Tags: ios, cocoa, class, frameworks

Cocoa provides a lot of functionality on the Security framework that iOS lacks, like these:

```
<Security/CMSDecoder.h>
<Security/SecAsn1Coder.h>
<Security/SecAsn1Templates.h>
<Security/SecRequirement.h>
```

Is there any framework/library/classes out there that can be used on an iOS project to replace those and provide the same functionality?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: nope, I ended using the solution on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a security.framework is present in iOS. This will allow you to do hashing, AES, CC3 etc.

Comment: but it is not as complete as cocoa's.

Comment: Check for <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h> file.